# pandas using groupby and filter based on value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, filtering

I have a pandas dataframe df which looks like this:

```
| source_num| source_date| text      | category    |location    | source |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+---
|  0      | 15/12/2020 | text1       | cat 1       | loc1       |soucrce1|
|  1      | 15/12/2020 | text2       | cat 2       | loc2       |source 2|
|  2      | 15/12/2020 | text3       | cat 3       | loc2       |source 3|
|  3      | 15/12/2020 | text4       | cat 2       | loc3       |source 2|
| ...     | ...        | ...         |             |            |        |
```

Now i can groupby this dataframe by the Item column and perform some aggregations on the value:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['category','source_num',"source","location"]).aggregate('sum')
```

the above statement return the correct result.

But when i try to perform some filter on the **groupby** object it return the below error :

```
grouped.filter(lambda x: x['location']== 'loc2')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-d8176314331e> in <module>
      3 
      4 grouped = wasi2adf.groupby(['category    ','source_num',"source","location"]).aggregate('sum')
----> 5 grouped.filter(lambda x: x['location']== 'loc2')
      
f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in filter(self, items, like, regex, axis)
   4618         if items is not None:
   4619             name = self._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 4620             return self.reindex(**{name: [r for r in items if r in labels]})
   4621         elif like:
   4622 

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

## EXCPECTED RESULT after the filtering:

```
| source_num| source_date| text      | category    |location    | source |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+---
|  0      | 15/12/2020 | text2       | cat 2       | loc2       |soucrce2|
|  1      | 15/12/2020 | text3       | cat 3       | loc2       |source 3|
```

Comment: ``groupby`` generates an iterable, that you cannot readily filter without an aggregation. You may have to filter your data before running the groupby. Have a look at the examples in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration) on how [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) is actually used.

Comment: so based on your comment the filter can't be done in order get the required result ... and i can't filter my data before the groubpy because i do not need the initial dataframe but i want the groupby result to run the filter on it

Comment: I'm assuming your source dataframe is what you have shared. Kindly share what you expected after filtering the groupby

Comment: my bad. `grouped` is a dataframe, not a groupby object, so you do not need filter. Just use `loc` or `query`.  Try this : ``grouped = (
    df.groupby(["category", "source_num", "source", "location"], as_index=False)
    .aggregate("sum")
    .query("location == 'loc2'")
)``

Comment: i tried your answer but it display this error :
`UndefinedVariableError: name 'location ' is not defined`

Comment: you have a `location` variable in columns, so ignore the query part and select your columns using `loc`. It should work, but we can choose to ignore that and just use `loc`

Comment: i replace `.query` with  `.loc` 
still display the below error:
`ValueError: No axis named location == 'loc2' for object type DataFrame
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
grouped = df.groupby(['category','source_num',"source","location"], as_index = False).aggregate('sum')
```

Then filter for the specific values in `location`:

```
 grouped.loc[grouped["location"] == "loc2"]


category    source_num  source  location    source_date text
1   cat 2   1   source 2    loc2    15/12/2020  text2
3   cat 3   2   source 3    loc2    15/12/2020  text3
```

Comment: this was the correct answer thank you.

how about if i want to iterate over the groupby object  to get the same result  for **loc2**

Comment: I guess it is possible. but why would you want to do that. It would be slower than working with Pandas built in methods

Answer (score 0):

```
type_group= df.groupby(['location']).filter(lambda x: (x['location'] == 'loc1').any())
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is not what i want

Comment: I have updated my answer and it should work. Please check it.

Comment: let me know whether the solution is working or not?